# Underline of Edittext control disappears in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using the **Holo Dark** Theme in my Android application in Xamarin. I devided my page (Activity) in different layouts. And I gave one the left layouts a white background (in contrast to the default black background of the Holo Dark Theme).
The Edittext controls in the dark side have the default gray underline bellow the edittext control (right side). 
But this underline has now disappeared in the white area.  Look at the picture:
[image]

I don't know why. How can I make the line visible again?

Comment: Could you post the .axml file that contains the layout with the white background?

Comment: I talked to the folks of Xamarin and they said that there the only way out is to use XML files and images that have a grey underline. Thus I solved it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom border of EditText control is draw as a background on Android. Maybe you changed the background of EditText controls so that the gray bottom borders are disappeared.